# Function runs on resize, but not on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run the carouselPartialView function when the page loads, but when I try to call the function, it doesn't run, but when I try to call it with the resizeWitdthOnly function it works. How can I make it to run on page load.

```
function resizeWidthOnly(a, b) {
    var c = [window.innerWidth];
    return onresize = function () {
        var d = window.innerWidth,
            e = c.length;
        c.push(d);
        if (c[e] !== c[e - 1]) {
            clearTimeout(b);
            b = setTimeout(a, 250);
        }
    }, a;
}

function carouselPartialView() {
    // settings
    var carousel = $("#carousel");
    var interval = 1000;
    var speed = 600;
    var xs_max = 767;
    var gutter = 30;
    var opacity = .7;
    // Derived vars.
    var wrapper = $(".wrapper");
    var slides = $(carousel).find('.slide').css('opacity', opacity);
    var carousel_width = $(carousel).width();
    var first_slide = $(slides[0]).css('opacity', 1);
    // Initial sizing and positioning.
    if (carousel_width >= xs_max) {
        // Let the css take over.
        $(slides).css('width', '');
    } else {
        $(slides).css('width', carousel_width + 'px');
        offset = 0;
    }
    var slide_width = $(first_slide).width();
    var offset = ((carousel_width - slide_width) / 2);
    $(wrapper).css('margin-left', offset);
    $(wrapper).width(slides.length * slide_width);

    // Click event listner
    $(slides).click(function () {
        slide_to(this);
    });
    function slide_to(elm) {
        // Slide to the current slide.
        var idx = $(slides).index(elm);
        $(wrapper).stop().animate({ 'margin-left': -(idx * slide_width) + offset }, speed)
        // Set the clicked slide to full opacity and nested fade out animation.
        $(elm).stop().css('opacity', 1, $(function () {
            $(slides).not(elm).stop().animate({ 'opacity': opacity }, speed / 3 * 2);
        }));
    }
};
// Init and resize.
resizeWidthOnly(function () {
    carouselPartialView();
})();
```

Comment: call function in ready

Comment: Like this ?
$(document).ready(function() {
    carouselPartialView();
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .ready() function. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    carouselPartialView();
});
```

Read more about it here: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @MateoHoxha is the function being executed? Try to place a console.log inside the function to make sure it's being called.

Comment: To me, it seems like you're trying to work with dynamically created elements that for some reason you're not able to handle when the DOM is ready. The .ready() function should work, or at least be called. If it isn't, there's something outside the code you shared that is not working properly.

Comment: If I console.log something, it logs in the console, but the contents don't load

Comment: Then it has something to do with the elements you're handling. Try to separate all of them and see which one is not loading properly. Check your $("#carousel") element.

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.onload`

jQuery

```
$(window).load(carouselPartialView());
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = carouselPartialView();
```

Answer (score 0):

chances that your code doesn't work at the beginning because the content of the carousel hasn't loaded yet, in order to confirm this try to delay the execution of the function by using setTimeout, although this isn't the proper solution it still helps you determine why your code isn't working:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        carouselPartialView();
        },4000)
    });
```

if after 4 seconds nothing happens, this means the issue is coming from something else

Comment: It works after 4 seconds, but I want it to execute direct on page load

Comment: can you post your carousel html code? we need to understand how your carousel is being loaded in order to know when to call the function